# warning : Implicit declaration error

Tags: c, include, warnings

Here's the files , i want to use includes :
primitives.h:

```
#ifndef PRIMITIVES_H_
#define PRIMITIVES_H_
#include "bloc.h"
#endif
```

primitives.c

```
#include "primitives.h"
Bloc_T creat2(char* ,BT_T); 

Bloc_T creat2(char* nomfic ,BT_T typefic)
{
Bloc_T Nouv_Bloc;
setTitreMeta(Nouv_Bloc.infosFic,nomfic);
Nouv_Bloc.typeBloc= typefic; 
return Nouv_Bloc;
}
```

bloc.h:

```
#ifndef STRUCTURES_H_INCLUDED
#define STRUCTURES_H_INCLUDED

// BIBLIOTHEQUES STANDARDS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>

// MACROS
#define TAILLE_BD 20
#define NBR_BLOC_PAR_FIC 5

struct Metadonnees
{
char* nomFic;

};
// Alias
    typedef struct Metadonnees MD_T;


enum blocType{
    BV,BD,BREP,BI
};
```

// Alias
    typedef enum blocType BT_T;

```
struct Bloc
{
    BT_T typeBloc;
    int** adressesInodes;  //tableau des adresses des BD (BI ou BRep)
    MD_T infosFic;
    char* data;  //bloc données
    char** nomsFic; // pour les BRep
    // bloc vide: tout à null
};
// Alias
typedef struct Bloc Bloc_T;
```

I get this warning:

```
primitives.c:8:2: attention : implicit declaration of function ‘setTitreMeta’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

But i have defined it in bloc.c.

Edit: Bloc.c
    #include "bloc.h"

```
void setTitreMeta(MD_T , char* );
void setTitreMeta(MD_T meta, char* titre)
{
    int taille = strlen(titre);
    meta.nomFic=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*taille);
    strcpy(meta.nomFic,titre);
    printf("Nom du fichier: %s\n",meta.nomFic);
}
```

I'm defining it in bloc.c but it shows me the warning .. where should I define it ( declare it )?

Comment: Well, `setTitreMeta` is not prototyped anywhere in the code you've posted, so what else do you expect?

Comment: Here I have added the bloc.c , but always the warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But i have defined it in bloc.c.

You may have *defined* it, but you also have to *declare* it

Declaring said function in `bloc.h` should fix it.

Comment: Here it work , when i define the function in bloc.h, why it doesnt work when I do that in Bloc.c ?

Comment: Because there is a difference in declaring a function vs defining one.
In the declaration you are basically saying the return type and number and types of the arguments. For example:

`int foo( int , int );` <- This goes in the .h file.

In the definition you are saying what the function actually does. For example:

`int foo(int a, int b){
 int c;
  c=a+b;
return c;
}`

The code above goes in the .c file. Hope I've cleared it up :)
Sorry for bad formatting, I'm new here.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler does not say that the function is not defined. It says that the function is not declared before its usage in file `primitives.c` where there is its call

```
setTitreMeta(Nouv_Bloc.infosFic,nomfic);
```

So the compiler is unable to say whether this call is valid.

Comment: so you mean that i have to use it ? But i'm using it in creat2 function

Comment: @user3568611 The compiler need to see the function declaration that to determine whether the function call is correct.